# Kafka consumer not consuming

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Here is my code for building a kafka consumer from the java client.

```
  def buildConsumer[Key, Value](
    configuration: KafkaConfiguration, commitInterval: Long, groupId: Option[String] = None)(
    implicit keyDeserializer: Deserializer[Key], valueDeserializer: Deserializer[Value]
  ): KafkaJavaConsumer[Key, Value] = {
    val settingsMap: Map[String, Object] = Map(
      "bootstrap.servers" -> s"${configuration.bootstrapHost}:${configuration.bootstrapPort}",
      "group.id" -> groupId.getOrElse(s"${configuration.topic}-${UUID.randomUUID}"),
      "enable.auto.commit" -> "true",
      "auto.commit.interval.ms" -> commitInterval.toString,
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest"
    ) ++ configuration.additionalOptions.getOrElse(Map.empty[String, Object])
    val consumer = new KafkaJavaConsumer[Key, Value](settingsMap.asJava, keyDeserializer, valueDeserializer)
    consumer.subscribe(Seq(configuration.topic).asJava)
    consumer
  }
```

My kafka is running on port 6050 and I have tested it in the console to produce and consume from that specific port. Im wondering if my problem is related to my configuration above. I have also tested the code above with the `EmbeddedKafka` framework, the issue appears to be with an actual kafka server running.

## EDIT:

I forgot to add that I have multiple consumers (with different `group.id`'s) consuming from the same broker, not sure if this is the problem.

Comment: Can you paste the consumer logs here with DEBUG mode enabled ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that,

> No. of partitions in the topic >= No. of consumer instances in the
>   group

Otherwise, some of the consumer instances in the group won't be assigned any partitions.

To check the number of partitions, use the kafka-topics.sh command

`> sh kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test --describe
Topic:test  PartitionCount:6    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
    Topic: test Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
    Topic: test Partition: 1    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
    Topic: test Partition: 2    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
    Topic: test Partition: 3    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
    Topic: test Partition: 4    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
    Topic: test Partition: 5    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0`

Answer (score 0):

Im still not sure as to what the problem is, but by deleting the zookeeper data folder and all the kafka logs, the consumer/producer began to work as intended. I think this may have had to do with the problem of me deleting the log files to clear the topics without using the formal kafka admin tools for topic deletion.